# If type is not string not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with lists:

```
text = ['package1:', 'package2:', 'package1,', ['package2', 'package4'], 'package3:', ['package2', 'package1,'], ['package3', 'package10,'], 'package60']
```

What i would like to do is working with the strings on one side, and the sublists on the other.

If i write:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(type(text[i]))
    if text[i] != str:
        print(text[i],'Not String')
    else:
        print(text[i],'String')
```

The output is the following

```
<class 'str'>
package1: Not String
<class 'str'>
package2: Not String
<class 'str'>
package1, Not String
<class 'list'>
['package2', 'package4'] Not String
<class 'str'>
package3: Not String
<class 'list'>
['package2', 'package1,'] Not String
<class 'list'>
['package3', 'package10,'] Not String
<class 'str'>
package60 Not String
```

Which is not correct since `package1:` is actually a string.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print(type(text[i]))
if text[i] != str:
```

You print `type(text[i])` (the type) but are comparing `text[i]` (the value) with the type. So of course you end up with results that seem to make no sense. Just compare the type with `str` and it will work.

That being said, the recommended way to check a type is using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(text[i], str):
    print(text[i], 'String')
else:
    print(text[i], 'Not String')
```

Comment: For python2 use `basestring` as an second argument to `isinstance()`. It's common class for `str` and `unicode`.

Comment: @ŁukaszR.: Unless you actually want to test just `str` and not both types, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your if condition in for loop like this

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(type(text[i]))
    if type(text[i]) != str:
        print(text[i],'Not String')
    else:
        print(text[i],'String')
```

I'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Comment: Talking about optimization, the code can be fit in two lines.
```for item in text:```
```print(type(item), item, 'String' if isinstance(item, str) else 'Not string')```

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy That doesn’t really make the code better.